# function prototype with *structure?

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list

i have a question concerning the usage of pointers in the function prototype, for example if we have:

```
Node *AppendList (Node *new_node, Node *head)
{
    Node *walker = head;
    if (head == NULL) 
        return new_node; 
    while (walker->next != NULL)
        walker = walker->next;
    walker->next = new_node;
    return head;
}
```

My question is: why does *AppendList have that * in it? Thanks!

Comment: Because you're returning a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning a pointer your function prototype should be **Node *AppendList**